# Serially deleting the same answer

Tags: discussion

Is there any way to constrain the behavior on [Is there a philosophy that suggests a motive to achieve great things which is deeper than one's own self?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/28702/9166), demonstrated by https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/28711/9166, and https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/28703/9166?

This seems to be an obvious example of manipulating the system, and although it is harmless, it demonstrates an unwillingness to take the site, and the others here, seriously.

Answer (score 2):

We don't have the power to change how the Stackexchange systsem works either as a community or as mods.

Bringing it to mod's attention using flags is a good step as is raising it on meta.

If a user continues to abuse the system in that way, mods do have (and will use) the power to suspend their accounts. We try to reserve this recourse for those who seem unable to work within the bounds of the site, generally by manifest rudeness or continuous nonsense answers.

Comment: It's true that (1) no one has an obligation to discuss with anyone here and (2) no one should troll, but also that (3) deleting your answer and reposting the same answer to ditch comments is also an abuse of the system.

Comment: But in the system, others have a right to comment. And deleting the same answer to ditch the comments is trying to  abrogate that right. If you think comments are inappropriate (not merely you disagree with them), then **flag them so that a moderator can look**. Deleting answers and reposting them is not the solution.

Comment: I am not a spammer or a troll.  The comments were challenging but not insulting and they represented my genuine reaction,not some basic disagreeability or other agenda (ergo not troll).  And they were not repetitious or off topic (ergo not spam).

Comment: @jobermark I did not take your comments there to be trolling, which is why I left them on the existing answer with very slight modification. / While John Am is correct that answerers can choose to delete answers, the purpose of this is if they are not confident in the answer, not to dodge comments they think are from "trolls".  Rather than fighting each other, **flag it immediately**.